# On a special decomposition of a $3\times 3$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, orthogonal-matrices

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$ be a diagonalizable matrix with strictly positive eigenvalues. (Note that $A$ is not required to be symmetric.)

Let $A_S$ be the symmetric part of $A$, that is
$$
A_S = \frac{1}{2}(A+A^\top).
$$
Suppose that $A_S$ possesses only one positive eigenvalue. In this case, since the vector of eigenvalues of $A_S$ always majorizes the vector $d=[\mathrm{tr}(A)\ 0\ 0]$ we can find an orthogonal matrix $T\in\mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$ such that $\tilde{A}_S=TA_S T^\top$ has diagonal $d$ ([Schur-Horn Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%E2%80%93Horn_theorem)).

By applying the same orthogonal transformation $T\in\mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$ to $A$, we obtain
$$\tag{$\ast$} \label{eq:ast}
\tilde{A}=T A T^\top = \begin{bmatrix}\mathrm{tr}(A) & \tilde{a}_{12} & \tilde{a}_{13} \\ \tilde{a}_{21} & 0 & \tilde{a}_{23} \\ \tilde{a}_{31} &  \tilde{a}_{32} & 0 \end{bmatrix},
$$
where $\tilde{a}_{ij}$ are suitable real numbers.

> With reference to the form in Eq. \eqref{eq:ast}:
>
> 1. Does there exist an orthogonal $T$ such that $\tilde{A}$ is **sign skew-symmetric**, that is $\mathrm{sign}(\tilde{a}_{ij})= - \mathrm{sign}(\tilde{a}_{ji})$ for all $i\ne j$?
> 2. If so, is it possible to find an orthogonal $T$ which further yields $\tilde{a}_{12}\tilde{a}_{23}\tilde{a}_{31}=-\tilde{a}_{21}\tilde{a}_{32}\tilde{a}_{13}$?